# How do I override Material-UI with css modules in create-react-app and Typescript?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, css-modules

For example I want to add flex my `h1` with class `pageTitle`

```js
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
const styles = require('./Header.module.css');

<div className={styles.header}>
   <AppBar>
      <Typography>
         <h1 className={styles.pageTitle}>HELLO</h1>
      </Typography>
   </AppBar>
</div>
```

In my *Header.module.css* file

```css
.pageTitle {
   display: flex;
   border-top: 10px;
}
```

Is this possible to do? Because its not changing anything on my end, again using Typescript, but following the same process as the docs that Material UI shows for css modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably material-ui selectors are ["stronger"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Material-ui supply several ways to [override](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/) their styles.

For example, use [`classes`](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes). In your case:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    borderTop: '10px solid orange'
  }
});

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <AppBar classes={classes}>
      <Typography>
          <h1>HELLO</h1>
      </Typography>
    </AppBar>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-override-styles-classes-v8nhl

BTW, `<AppBar />` already has `display: flex` and you set `borderTop` in a css file which is invalid (it should be `border-top`) so maybe if it was valid, it was working.